# How to create a custom pipeline of objects which are called in sequence?

Tags: python, oop, scikit-learn, pipeline

Scikit-learn have [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) functionality which is a Pipeline of transforms with a final estimator.

How do I create something which works with classes which don't have scikit learn fit & transform methods but have ____call___() instead? I dont want the solution to use scikit-learn pipeline. So I want to do the below actions in the order listed below

1. Pass a dict to ppl which pass the dict to A().____call____()
2. Output df returned by step 1. is passed to B().____call____()
3. Output returned by step 2. is passed to C().____call____()
4. Output returned by step 3. is passed to a lambda function which returns sum of the two columns A & B

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

class A:
    def __init__(self, sample=1):
        self.sample = sample

    def __call__(self, dct):
        return pd.DataFrame(dct)[:self.sample]

class B:
    def __init__(self, col1, col2):
        self.col1 = col1
        self.col2 = col2
    def __call__(self, df):
        return df[self.col1], df[self.col2]

class C:
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        return x+y


ppl = CustomPipeline(pipeline=[('A', A(sample=700)),
                               ('B', B(col1='A', col2='B')),
                               ('C', C())
                               ('self', lambda x: x)])
df_sum = ppl(dct={'A': [1, 2, 4], 'B': [10, 2, 3]})
```

**Question**

- How do I implement CustomPipeline() so that it will work according to the example I listed above?
- Is using main() in each of the class better than implementing ____call___() method in the classes?

Answer (score 2):

```py
from typing import Sequence, Tuple, Callable, Any

def CustomPipeline(pipeline: Sequence[Tuple[str, Callable[[Any], Any]]]) -> Callable[[Any], Any]:
    def _run(value: Any) -> Any:
        for name, stage in pipeline:
            value = stage(value)
        return value
    return _run

>>> ppl = CustomPipeline([('a', lambda v: v*2), ('b', lambda v: v+1)])
>>> ppl(5)
11
```

The outer function is used to create a closure with the stages of the pipeline.

This could be implemented with a class just as easily.

Comment: Interesting. What if instead of lambda v: v*2 its a class?

Comment: Any `Callable[[Any], Any]` should work, so as long as it takes one argument to construct, it's fine. If instead you mean an instance of a class (ie. an object), it's also OK and also needs to be Callable (as in your examples).